# pandas argmax returns an unexpected value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am calling the argmax function by print as:

```
print(piTot)
print(piTot[piTot.argmax()],",",piTot.argmax())
```

And getting the following output:

```
0        0.000000
1      137.077960
2      258.248535
3      452.867526
4      526.315944
5      583.856975
6      625.490621
7      651.216882
14     661.035756
8      654.947245
15     632.951348
9      595.048066
16     541.237397
10     471.519343
11     385.893904
12     284.361079
17     166.920868
18      33.573271
19    -115.681712
13    -280.844080
20    -461.913834
21    -658.890973
22    -871.775498
23   -1100.567409
24   -1345.266706
dtype: float64
654.9472450175853 , 8
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
661.035756 , 14
```

Where is the problem because I cannot see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In your example, `piTot` is a [`pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html).

  - *I generated piTot by multiplying price series with corresponding ols estimations*

    - This creates a `pandas.Series` where the [`dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#basics-dtypes) is `float64`
  - Given [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), `df`, below, your equivalent `Series` is `piTot = df['val']`
  - That you are using a `Series`, is why `piTot[piTot.argmax()]` doesn't result in a `KeyError`

    - The expected value requires the index number, `piTot[piTot.idxmax()]`, not the index label.
- Note the difference in what is returned by [`.argmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html), compared to [`.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html)

```py
# Return index of first occurrence of maximum over requested axis.
idx = df['val'].idxmax()

# Return int position of the largest value in the Series.
arg = df['val'].argmax()

print(idx, arg)
[out]:
(14, 8)

# use loc with the label
df.loc[idx]
[out]:
1    661.035756
Name: 14, dtype: float64

# use iloc with the int position
df.iloc[arg]
1    661.035756
Name: 14, dtype: float64
```

```py
print(f'Use iloc with argmax:\n{df.iloc[arg]}')
print(f'\nNumeric Location: {arg}')
print(f'\nUse loc with idxmax\n{df.loc[idx]}')
print(f'\nLabel Location: {idx}')
[out]:
Use iloc with argmax:
val    661.035756
Name: 14, dtype: float64

Numeric Location: 8

Use loc with idxmax
val    661.035756
Name: 14, dtype: float64

Label Location: 14
```

### Data

```py
# create dataframe from clipboard
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=[0])

# copy to clipboard
,val
0,0.0
1,137.07796
2,258.248535
3,452.867526
4,526.315944
5,583.856975
6,625.490621
7,651.216882
14,661.035756
8,654.947245
15,632.951348
9,595.048066
16,541.237397
10,471.519343
11,385.893904
12,284.361079
17,166.920868
18,33.573271
19,-115.681712
13,-280.84408
20,-461.913834
21,-658.890973
22,-871.775498
23,-1100.567409
24,-1345.266706
```

Comment: That was a great insight and now I see the difference between those functions, thank you very much sir.